# Why my code in VB 6 is not working?

Tags: vb6

I need a code when you Type (A,I,O,U,E) count character .. I wrote this But It doesn't work .. Please help me.. sorry for my bad English

```
n = Val(InputBox("enter a number"))
For i = 1 To Len(n)
      k = Mid(n, i, 1)
      k = LCase k
     Select Case k
          Case "a""i""o""u""e": t = t + 1

     End Select

Next
Print t
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: My code Dose not work ..  I need to know where I typed wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`val()` will convert the input value to a number so there will never be any vowels.. removing it and correcting the missing commas in the case condition:

```
Dim n As String, t As Long
n = InputBox("enter a number")

For i = 1 To Len(n)
    Select Case LCase$(Mid$(n, i, 1))
        Case "a", "i", "o", "u", "e": t = t + 1
    End Select
Next
Print t
```

Comment: Don't forget to help others and mark the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking on the literal string `a"i"o"u"e`, which is clearly not your intention.

You probably intended:

```
n = Val(InputBox("enter a number"))
For i = 1 To Len(n)
     k = Mid(n, i, 1)
     k = LCase k
     Select Case k
          Case "a", "i", "o", "u", "e": t = t + 1
     End Select

Next
Print t
```

You can [read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) on how `Case` statements work.

Comment: Agin nothing  happen ...

Comment: As @AlexK pointed out in his more extensive answer, you're converting a String to an Integer using `Val()`.

Comment: It also won't compile as is due to lack of brackets on the `LCase` call.

Comment: Correct! Again, @AlexK's answer covers all three problems with the code whereas mine only points out the correct usage of `Case` statements.